# Sending basic commands to the Oculus Go running a unity app

Tags: api, networking, raspberry-pi, oculus, oculusgo

I want to use a raspberry pi as a server and send simple commands to several Oculus Go's running a unity app. I have experience with API's so ideally I would like to send some HTTP requests to these Oculus Go's but I don't know if it's possible to have some sort of http server on the Oculus. What is the best way to do this? latency isn't very important and the messages sent will be fairly infrequently. I probably want to have a golang program running on the raspberry pi that then sends the network commands to the unity app on the Oculus. I already asked this question on the official oculus forums but nobody responded, does anybody have thoughts on the best way to implement this? I saw that unity has a transport api for networking but I don't know if that is the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using an httpListener in c#. [This example on github](https://gist.github.com/amimaro/10e879ccb54b2cacae4b81abea455b10) was very helpful to make it happen in unity.